# How to keep duplicates with Pandas while using CPI library?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to inflation adjust 2 columns in a csv file, but pandas is removing duplicates which is resulting in loss of data.

Here's a sample of my dataset:

| Bank Name | Year | Closing Date | Asset | Deposit | City | State |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Signature Bank | 2023 | 12-Mar-23 | 110400 | 88600 | New York | NY |
| Signature Bank | 2011 | 8-Jul-11 | 66.7 | 64.5 | Windsor | CO |

Here's a sample after running pandas:

| Bank Name | Year | Closing Date | Asset | Deposit | City | State | Inflation-Adj |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Signature Bank | 1/1/2011 | 8-Jul-11 | 66 | 64 | Windsor | CO | 85.86874664 |

I'm losing the second row of Signature Bank which is resulting in a loss of data.

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import cpi

# Read the CSV file
df = pd.read_csv('merged_file.csv')

# Mark all duplicates as True and keep them based on Asset, Deposit, State, and Acquiring Institution
duplicates = df.duplicated(subset=['Bank Name'], keep=False)

# Convert the 'Closing Date' column to datetime
df['Year'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Year'], format='%Y')

# Filter out any rows with dates after 2022-01-01
df = df[df['Year'] < pd.to_datetime('2023-01-01')]

# Convert the 'Asset' and 'Deposit' columns to integers
df['Asset'] = df['Asset'].astype(int)
df['Deposit'] = df['Deposit'].astype(int)

# Create new columns for inflation-adjusted 'Asset' and 'Deposit' values
df['Inflation-Adjusted Asset'] = df.apply(lambda x: cpi.inflate(int(x['Asset']), int(x['Year'].year)), axis=1)
df['Inflation-Adjusted Deposit'] = df.apply(lambda x: cpi.inflate(int(x['Deposit']), int(x['Year'].year)), axis=1)

# Write the updated DataFrame to a new CSV file
df.to_csv('inflation_adjusted.csv', index=False)
```

I've tried different ways of retaining duplicates, and adding other columns in the subset parameter, but i'm still losing rows where i have duplicates of bank names.

Is there a way to stop this?

Any help or insight is deeply appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It's not deleting duplicates.  YOU are deleting all rows dated in 2023 and beyond when you do `df[df['Year'] < pd.to_datetime('2023-01-01')]`.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thanks I forgot I did that. The reason is that the cpi library doesn't have data after 2023-01-01 so I had to tell it to stop there otherwise I get an error when trying to convert values in 2023. Is there another way around this?

Comment: Another way around what?  If you need to limit your data to before 2023, then you have exactly what you need.  Right?

Comment: @TimRoberts Yea I realized how stupid it was to write that after sending it. Thanks for clarifying everything for me.